Flutter Single responsibility principle with Provider package - clean code
I am trying to understand how to better write my Flutter application as right now with the current approach, the size of my service file is getting out of hand. Here is my use case (simplified):
I have the following master model called Person. Person is a 'wrapper' and it contains multiple sub-classes such as:

List addresses;
List pets;
and quite a few others.

Now according to provider documentation I have created a single service, which I use to store data regarding 'Person'
class ApplicationDataController with ChangeNotifier {
  ApplicationDataController(this._dataService);

  List<AppPerson> allItems = [];
  AppPerson? selectedPerson;

  //Method used to populate `allItems` into the application
  Future<void> initialize() async {
    allItems = await _dataService.getAllData();
    if (allItems.isNotEmpty) {
      selectedPerson = allItems.first;
    }
  }

  ...other code (I will share later in article)
}

in my main.dart. I have pluged this model into ChangeNotifierProvider as stated in documentation.
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final appDataController =
      ApplicationDataController(ApplicationDataPersistenceService());
  await appDataController.initialize();

  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) =>
          appDataController,
      child: const MyApp()));
}

Finally in my views if I want to bind to specific item under selectedPerson, such as List of selectedPerson.pets I simply use Consumer<T> widget provided by the package as following:
body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Consumer<ApplicationDataController>(
              builder: (context, dataController, child) =>
                  _buildContent(context, dataController),
            )),
      ),

Up until this point the class implementation was nice and clean. However as soon as I wanted to add Add / Edit / Remove (CRUD) functionality, the code starts to blow up under ApplicationDataController. Here is a sample only for Pet model
  void addPet(String name, int age) {
    var pet = Pet(name,age);
    selectedPerson.addPet(pet);
    notifyListeners();
    saveDataInDatabase();
  }

  void removePet(int petId) {
    selectedPerson.removePet(petId);
    notifyListeners();
    saveDataInDatabase();
  }

  void updatePet(int petId, String name, int age) {
    var selectedPet = selectedPerson.getPetById(petId);
    selectedPet.updateData(name,age);
    notifyListeners();
    saveDataInDatabase();
  }

The more models I add under my Person class, the bigger the ApplicationDataController grows, which now becomes more and more unreadable.
As a workaround, I could directly access subsequent class methods from within the view (directly calling selectedPerson.addPet()) and under ApplicationDataController only have one method to notifyListeners and update new data to the database such as following:
  void saveLatestChanges() {
    notifyListeners();
    saveDataInDatabase();
  }

However this breaks single responsibility principle for my view classes as right now, they need to also process the 'business' aspect of the data processing; as CRUD methods might require access to other services, logging and other...which is the reason I feel that this belongs to service class.
Probably this could be achieved by either splitting these methods into individual classes such as

PetsService
AddressService
PersonService
...and others

Or maybe the same could be achieved by inheritance and injecting these instances in the constructor of the ApplicationDataController directly...or maybe there is even better elegant way that due to my lacking dart knowledge I do not know yet.
Any tips in respect to this matter would be highly appreciated.

In the end I managed to split my code into reasonable classes. I created the following class which holds the data about all People available in the application:
class ApplicationDataController with ChangeNotifier {
  ApplicationDataController(this._dataService);
  final IApplicationDataPersistence _dataService;

  List<AppPerson> allItems = [];   
  late AppPerson _selectedPerson;
  AppPerson get selectedPerson => _selectedPerson;

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    allItems = await _dataService.getAllData();
    if (allItems.isNotEmpty) {
      _selectedPerson = allItems.first;
    } else {
      _selectedPerson = AppPerson(name: 'Temporary');
    }
  }

  void selectAnotherPerson(int personId) {
      _selectedPerson = allItems[personId];

      notifyListeners();
  }
}

Now for all "child" classes that would be managing sub-classes such as

List<Address>
List<Pet>

... and others
I have first created a base class that all extend:
class ChildServiceControllerBase with ChangeNotifier {
  final IApplicationDataPersistence dataService;
  final ApplicationDataController dataController;

  ChildServiceControllerBase(
      {required this.dataService, required this.dataController});

  late AppPerson selectedPerson;
  void updateSelectedPerson(AppPerson person) {
    selectedPerson = person;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void notifyAndSaveData() {
    notifyListeners();
    dataController.saveDataInDatabase();
  }
}

Now child implementation would look as following:
class PetsDataController extends ChildServiceControllerBase {
  PetsDataController(
      {required super.dataService, required super.dataController});

  UnmodifiableListView<Pet> get allPets=>
      UnmodifiableListView(selectedPerson.pets);

  void addNewPet(
    String petName,
    int age        
  ) {        
    selectedPerson.addPet(petName, age);

    notifyAndSaveData();
  }
}

Finally (the reason why we have Base implementation for child classes) we use ProxyProvider, which helps us to re-draw UI when selectedPerson gets changed.
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final dataPersistenceService = ApplicationDataPersistenceService();

  final appDataController = ApplicationDataController(dataPersistenceService);
  await appDataController.initialize();

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ApplicationDataController>(
            create: (context) => appDataController),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<ApplicationDataController,
                PetsDataController>(
            create: (context) => PetsDataController(
                dataService: dataPersistenceService,
                dataController: appDataController),
            update: (_, myModel, myNotifier) =>
                myNotifier!..updateSelectedPerson(myModel.selectedPerson)),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

I am quite sure that there should be even more, elegant way how to achieve this; yet unfortunately it seems that Flutter is not that popular among community as over the past day this has barely got 15 views (which is shame as Flutter is awesome).
Happy coding guys!
